# jsf 2.0 reading <ul> tag as String "<ul>"

Tags: jsf

I wish to add ul tag to my jsf in some cases. My codes like:

```
<c:if test="${level ne 1}" >&lt;ul&gt;</c:if>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<c:if test="${level ne 1}" >&lt;/ul&gt;</c:if>
```

When I was using jsf 1.2, it works well. But after I change to jsf 2.0, it reads like

```
 "<ul>"
 <li>..</li>
 <li>..</li>
 <li>..</li>
 "</ul>"
```

How can I fix it? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have replaced legacy JSP by Facelets as well (well done!). This behaviour is specific to Facelets. It implicitly HTML-escapes all the template text as part of builtin XSS attack prevention.

Use `<h:outputText escape="false">` instead.

```
<c:if test="${level ne 1}"><h:outputText value="&lt;ul&gt;" escape="false" /></c:if>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<c:if test="${level ne 1}"><h:outputText value="&lt;/ul&gt;" escape="false" /></c:if>
```

You'd better use its `rendered` attribute instead of those ugly JSTL tags by the way.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;ul&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{level ne 1}" />
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<h:outputText value="&lt;/ul&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{level ne 1}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, for the concrete functional requirement, you may find [OmniFaces `<o:tree>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) useful.